# How can I include an object that is inside a list, that is inside another object?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, lambda

I need to check (for a filter), whether the name inside an object is the input's name.

I have a model called AppUser which is the IdentityUser. AppUser contains an object called UsersData. Inside UsersData, there is a List of Languages objects. Inside the Languages object, there is an object called LanguageName. Inside LanguageName, is the Name I need to compare.

I need to access it directly from the AppUser. I tried including the data, but I can include as far as to the list of languages, but not the fields inside the list.

I have tried the to use thenInclude, but since it is a list, I can't use then include.

AppUser Model:

```
    public class AppUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
        public UsersData UsersData { get; set; }

    }
```

UsersData Model:

```
public class UsersData
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public Gender Gender { get; set; }
        public City City { get; set; }
        public Company Company { get; set; }
        public Line Line { get; set; }
        public Area Area { get; set; }
        public List<AcademicRecord> AcademicRecords { get; set; }
        public List<MasterPostgraduate> MasterPostgraduates { get; set; }
        public List<Language> Languages { get; set; }
        public List<Technology> Technologies { get; set; }
        public List<Project> Projects { get; set; }
        public List<ProfessionalRecord> ProfessionalRecords { get; set; }
    }
```

Language Model:

```
    public class Language
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public LanguageName LanguageName { get; set; }
        public CertificationFile CertificationFile { get; set; }
        public int WritingLevel { get; set; }
        public int SpeakingLevel { get; set; }
        public int CertificationLevel { get; set; }
        public string CertificationName { get; set; }
        public DateTime CertificationDate { get; set; }
        public UsersData UserInfo { get; set; }
    }
```

LanguageName Model:

```
    public class LanguageName
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

The way I am trying to include the data:

```
            List<AppUser> users = await _userManager.Users
                .Include(x => x.UsersData.Technologies)
                .Include(y => y.UsersData.AcademicRecords)
                .Include(z => z.UsersData.Languages)
                .ToListAsync();
```

As for now, technologyName is null.

```
if(technoName != "")
{
    users = users.Where(x => x.UsersData.Technologies.Any(item => item.TechName.Name == technoName)).ToList();
}
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like the following :

```
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string technoName = "abc";
            UserManager _userManager = new UserManager();

            AppUser appUser = new AppUser() { Users = _userManager.Users.ToList() };

            var users = appUser.Users.SelectMany(x => x.Languages.Where(y => y.LanguageName.Name == technoName)).ToList();

        }

    }
    public class AppUser
    {
        public List<UsersData> Users { get; set; }
    }
    public class UserManager
    {
        public List<UsersData> Users { get; set; }
    }
    public class UsersData
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        //public Gender Gender { get; set; }
        //public City City { get; set; }
        //public Company Company { get; set; }
        //public Line Line { get; set; }
        //public Area Area { get; set; }
        //public List<AcademicRecord> AcademicRecords { get; set; }
        //public List<MasterPostgraduate> MasterPostgraduates { get; set; }
        public List<Language> Languages { get; set; }
        //public List<Technology> Technologies { get; set; }
        //public List<Project> Projects { get; set; }
        //public List<ProfessionalRecord> ProfessionalRecords { get; set; }
    }
    public class Language
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public LanguageName LanguageName { get; set; }
        //public CertificationFile CertificationFile { get; set; }
        public int WritingLevel { get; set; }
        public int SpeakingLevel { get; set; }
        public int CertificationLevel { get; set; }
        public string CertificationName { get; set; }
        public DateTime CertificationDate { get; set; }
        public UsersData UserInfo { get; set; }
    }
    public class LanguageName
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I just solved it also in a different way, thought it did not work ,but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Even though it is a list, I can use thenInclude, I may have misspelled something the first time.